# How can I get the summary of questions a user ask from the Stack Overflow data dump?

Tags: support, questions, data-explorer, users, data-dump

I need information about how many questions a user asks, how many of them are resolved, and how many of them remain unanswered. Is there any way to get this information from the SO data dump?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't use the data dump for this; there are easier ways to retrieve this information rather than having to parse a couple of GBs of XML. Enter the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com).

[This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/981468/question-statistics?numberOfRecords=100) provides information you might be looking for; the results are:

[image]

You can try asking for more than 100 hits, but it might run out of resources and fail if you do so. Maybe you want to exclude closed questions? If so, or you want to make other changes, feel free to [fork](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/fork/981468) the query. If you need some help with SQL and/or the structure of the database, check out the awesome [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) and the [chatroom](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede). Note that SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday morning.

Comment: I mean the questions that have an accepted answer as _'resolved'_ and _'unanswered'_ questions mean the questions have no answers. So, your query is alright. But I need this summary for all the users of Stack Overflow.

Comment: I've tried to make that one too, see the update.

Comment: It's really a great help.